# Magento : Not Saving Anything in Backend

Tags: magento-1.9

I've tried to search, but found nothing similar to what I'm facing. If I try to save anything in the backend, products, clients, it loads the "wait" mask forever and doesn't finish the saving process.

Strangest thing, it doesn't throw any error, not even in system.log, exception.log. if I inspect the requisitions being made, all of them have the 200 status code. So I'm out of clues on what to do next.

Comment: Have you check the magento console is there any error there?

Answer (score 0):

You can debug the issues in this way.

1. Check is there any error show on console or not? If show then try to resolve that one.
2. Try to disable all third party extension and check the error is due to any third party extension of not?
3. Take the backup of the current site, and run the compilation one's and then check.